# Trying to create a new column that sums multiple criteria in python

Tags: python, pandas

```
          Date AccountRef      Amount       Type
0   2019-04-15   REF0005  25000.00   cashflow_in
1   2019-04-15   REF004  20000.00   cashflow_in
2   2019-06-07   REF005   2000.00   cashflow_in
3   2019-07-24   REF005   3000.00   cashflow_in
4   2019-07-25   REF004   5000.00   cashflow_out
5   2019-08-08   REF004   5000.00   cashflow_in
6   2019-09-10   REF004   5000.00   cashflow_out
7   2019-10-13   REF005   5000.00   cashflow_out
8   2019-10-30   REF006   5000.00   cashflow_in
9   2019-11-08   REF009   2500.00   cashflow_out
10  2019-11-23   REF005   5000.00   cashflow_in
11  2019-11-30   REF011   5000.00   cashflow_out
```

Above is roughly my data set and I'm been trying to create a new column that sums of "Amount" if "AccountRef" is the same (so yes, there will be duplicate values), if type = cashflow_in, and date is after a date (eg using Date = 25/07/2020) for example).

I'll also be be another another column after this but the calculation method should be similar so I should be able to replace the filters/function again.

I've tried things like

```
> df = df[df['Type'] == 'cashflow_in'] 
> df['CumluativeIn'] = df.apply(lambda row: df[df['AccountRef'] == row['AccountRef']]['Amount'].sum(), axis=1)
```

but it doesn't really work the way it should.  It's based on a SumIF command from excel.

Edit as I got advised to do it.
My desire output is a value (or more precisely "sum") in each row where it meets those criteria (before a certain date, sum of when all values are the same as in the same row, and when type - cashflow_in).

The second weird criteria but afterwards I'll be adding a second column and varying the dates, sorry about my questions!

Edit 2: To show an example of what I want
Date before 2019-11-01

```
          Date AccountRef      Amount       Type Cumulative_In
0   2019-04-15   REF0005  25000.00   cashflow_in 30000.00
1   2019-04-15   REF004  20000.00   cashflow_in 25000.00
2   2019-06-07   REF005   2000.00   cashflow_in 30000.00
3   2019-07-24   REF005   3000.00   cashflow_in 30000.00
4   2019-07-25   REF004   5000.00   cashflow_out 25000.00
5   2019-08-08   REF004   5000.00   cashflow_in 25000.00
6   2019-09-10   REF004   5000.00   cashflow_out 25000.00
7   2019-10-13   REF005   5000.00   cashflow_out 30000.00
8   2019-10-30   REF006   5000.00   cashflow_in 5000.00
9   2019-11-08   REF009   2500.00   cashflow_out 0.00
10  2019-11-23   REF005   5000.00   cashflow_in 30000.00
11  2019-11-30   REF011   5000.00   cashflow_out 0.00
```

In the world of Excel (assuming 0 = A2 and F2 is first data point in the new column), this would be
New Column = Sumifs{Amount Column,

or more accurately

F2 = Sumifs{$D$2:$D$12,$C$2:$C$12,C2,$B$2:$B$12,< "2019-11-01",$F$2:$F$12 = "cashflow_in"}

Then F3 becomes
F3 = Sumifs{$D$2:$D$12,$C$2:$C$12,C3,$B$2:$B$12,< "2019-11-01",$F$2:$F$12 = "cashflow_in"}
F4 = Sumifs{$D$2:$D$12,$C$2:$C$12,C4,$B$2:$B$12,< "2019-11-01",$F$2:$F$12 = "cashflow_in"}

Comment: Check out the groupby function in the pandas documentation. Also - please provide a sample output so we know what the goal is.

Comment: Ah sorry my bad, I apoligise as I am still a bit new at this.

I'll have a look a groupby and see if I can get it to work and write a comment about it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pivot a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe)

Comment: 'Is 'REF0005' correct?' Why does 'REF0005' become 30,000 and why does 'REF004' also become 25,000?

Comment: It adds 25000.00 from rows 

2   2019-06-07   REF005   2000.00   cashflow_in 30000.00
3   2019-07-24   REF005   3000.00   cashflow_in 30000.00

but not (due to "cashflow_out")
7   2019-10-13   REF005   5000.00   cashflow_out 30000.00

and  (due to date)
10  2019-11-23   REF005   5000.00   cashflow_in 30000.00

Comment: omg that formatting was horrible

Comment: I had trouble with trying to get two spaces to <br> to work so here's an image of what I was trying to say.

https://i.imgur.com/HKdkiAG.png

Answer (score 0):

I may not understand the intent of your question. If you want to calculate the totals by account, you can achieve this with the following code.
Does this meet your intent?

```
df['CumluativeIn'] = df.groupby('AccountRef')['Amount'].cumsum()

df
Date    AccountRef  Amount  Type    CumluativeIn
0   2019-04-15  REF0005 25000.0 cashflow_in 25000.0
1   2019-04-15  REF004  20000.0 cashflow_in 20000.0
2   2019-06-07  REF005  2000.0  cashflow_in 2000.0
3   2019-07-24  REF005  3000.0  cashflow_in 5000.0
5   2019-08-08  REF004  5000.0  cashflow_in 25000.0
7   2019-10-13  REF005  5000.0  cashflow_in 10000.0
8   2019-10-30  REF006  5000.0  cashflow_in 5000.0
10  2019-10-23  REF007  5000.0  cashflow_in 5000.0
```

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your reply.

I think that's part of it but I need it to do more than totals by account.  I need it to also have a filter where it only sums total by account if the date in column 1 is before a certain date and where Type = cashflow_in.

I'm struggling for multiple criteria selection.

Comment: I'm sorry we can't meet your request. I think you could get a quicker answer if you could better organize and clarify the conditions and the desired output.

Comment: No, you guys have been more than helpful for me.  It is my fault for not being that clear.

I tried to edit to clarify my desired output (I tried to post in this comment but it is too long).

Answer (score 0):

After much fiddling, talking to my co workers, and such - I think I got it to work so I thought I'll post the answer here.

```
df_grouped = df.groupby('AccountRef')

facilities = df_grouped.groups.keys()
for facility in facilities:
    df_filtered = df_grouped.get_group(facility)
    df_filtered['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
    df_filtered = df_filtered.sort_values(by='Date')
    df_repayments = df_filtered[df_filtered['Type'] == 'cashflow_in']
    df_drawdowns = df_filtered[df_filtered['Type'] == 'cashflow_out']
    total_cashflow_in = df_cashflow_in['Amount'].sum()
    print(total_cashflow_in)
    df_drawdowns.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    for index, row in df_cashflow_out.iterrows():
        cashflow_out = row['Amount']
        current_value = cashflow_out - total_cashflow_in
        if current_value < 0:
            current_value = 0
            total_cashflow_in = total_cashflow_in - cashflow_out
        else:
            total_cashflow_in = 0
        df_cashflow_out.loc[index, 'current_value'] = current_value
```

print(df)